# How robots that are sent in space achieve automation?Are they based on conventional control techniques or they based on AI methods?

Tags: automation

How robots that are sent in space achieve automation?Are they based on conventional control techniques or they based on  AI methods?

Comment: `set gravity = MARS`

Comment: your second question makes an assumption that all of the robots use the same control type